# Fastest way to sum columns with lag

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, vectorization

Given a square matrix, I want to shift each row by its row-number and sum the columns. For example:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],        array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],    ->            [3, 4, 5],      ->   array([0, 1+3, 2+4+6, 5+7, 8]) = array([0, 4, 12, 12, 8])
       [6, 7, 8]])                    [6, 7, 8]])
```

I have 4 solutions - [`fast`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088714/14923227), `slow`, [`slower`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67335338/14923227) and `slowest`, which do exactly the same thing and are ranked by speed:

```
def fast(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    retval = np.zeros(2*n-1)
    for i in range(n):
        retval[i:(i+n)] += A[i, :]
    return retval
```

```
def slow(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    indices = np.arange(n)
    indices = indices + indices[:,None]
    return np.bincount(indices.ravel(), A.ravel())
```

```
def slower(A):
    r, _ = A.shape
    retval = np.c_[A, np.zeros((r, r), dtype=A.dtype)].ravel()[:-r].reshape(r, -1)
    return retval.sum(0)
```

```
def slowest(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    retval = np.zeros(2*n-1)
    indices = np.arange(n)
    indices = indices + indices[:,None]
    np.add.at(retval, indices, A)
    return retval
```

Surprisingly, the non-vectorized solution is the fastest. Here is my benchmark:

```
A = np.random.randn(1000,1000)

%timeit fast(A)
# 1.85 ms ± 20 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit slow(A)
# 3.28 ms ± 9.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit slower(A)
# 4.07 ms ± 18.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit slowest(A)
# 58.4 ms ± 993 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

Does there exist a faster solution? And if not, can someone explain why in fact `fast` is the fastest?

**EDIT**

A slight speedup for `slow`:

```
def slow(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    indices = np.arange(2*n-1)
    indices = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(indices, A.shape, (8,8))
    return np.bincount(indices.ravel(), A.ravel())
```

Plotting the runtime in the same way as Pierre did (with 2**15 as upper bound - for some reason `slow` does not handle this size)
[image]

`slow` is marginally faster than any solution (not using `numba`) for arrays that are `100x100`. `sum_antidiagonals` is still the best for `1000x1000` arrays.

Comment: Noticed that I can shave ~0.87 ms off ```slow``` by generating the cartesian indices using ```np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided```.

Comment: On _why_ `fast()` is the fastest: using a slice as an l-value is very clever and very fast with `numpy`. The overall function does pretty much the minimal amount of operations needed (`r*c` additions, or `n^2` in your terminology), in addition to the Python `for` loop; the cost of the `for` loop is only `O(n)` (with small time constants) and becomes negligible by contrast to the `O(n^2)` of the additions. Thus `fast()` asymptotically reaches the speed of `just_sum_0()`, which got to be the fastest operation for `O(n^2)` additions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way that **is sometimes faster** than your "`fast()`" version, but only in a limited range of `n` (roughly between 30 and 1000) for a `n x n` array. The loop (`fast()`) is **very hard to beat on large arrays**, even using `numba`, and actually converges asymptotically to the time of simply `a.sum(axis=0)`, which indicates that this is about as efficient as it gets for large arrays (kudos to your loop!)

The method, which I'll call `sum_antidiagonals()`, uses `np.add.reduce()` on a striped version of `a` and on a made-up mask from a relatively small 1D array that is striped to create the illusion of a 2D array (without consuming more memory).

Additionally, it is not limited to square arrays (but `fast()` can be easily adapted for this generalization as well, see `fast_g()` at the bottom of this post).

```py
def sum_antidiagonals(a):
    assert a.flags.c_contiguous
    r, c = a.shape
    s0, s1 = a.strides
    z = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        a, shape=(r, c+r-1), strides=(s0 - s1, s1), writeable=False)
    # mask
    kern = np.r_[np.repeat(False, r-1), np.repeat(True, c), np.repeat(False, r-1)]
    mask = np.fliplr(np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        kern, shape=(r, c+r-1), strides=(1, 1), writeable=False))
    return np.add.reduce(z, where=mask)
```

Notice that it isn't limited to a square array:

```py
>>> sum_antidiagonals(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3))
array([ 0,  4, 12, 21, 30, 24, 14])
```

**Explanation**

To understand how that works, let's examine these striped arrays with an example.

Given an initial array `a` that is `(3, 2)`:

```py
a = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2)
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

# after calculating z in the function
>>> z
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

You can see that it is almost what we want to `sum(axis=0)`, except that the lower and upper triangles are unwanted. What we would really like to sum looks like:

```
array([[0, 1, -, -],
       [-, 2, 3, -],
       [-, -, 4, 5]])
```

Enter the mask, which we can build starting from a 1D kernel:

```py
kern = np.r_[np.repeat(False, r-1), np.repeat(True, c), np.repeat(False, r-1)]
>>> kern
array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False])
```

We use a funny slice: `(1, 1)`, which means that we repeat the same row, but sliding by one element each time:

```py
>>> np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
...        kern, shape=(r, c+r-1), strides=(1, 1), writeable=False)
array([[False, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False]])
```

We then just flip this left/right, and use it as the `where` argument for `np.add.reduce()`.

**Speed**

```py
b = np.random.normal(size=(1000, 1000))

# check equivalence with the OP's fast() function:
>>> np.allclose(fast(b), sum_antidiagonals(b))
True

%timeit sum_antidiagonals(b)
# 1.83 ms ± 840 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit fast(b)
# 2.07 ms ± 15.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

In this case, it is a little bit faster, but only by about 10%.

On a 300x300 array, `sum_antidiagonals()` is 2.27x faster than `fast()`.

**However!**

Even though putting together `z` and `mask` is very fast (the whole setup before `np.add.reduce()` takes only 46 µs in the 1000x1000 example above), the summation itself is `O[r (r+c)]`, even though only `O[r c]` actual additions (where `mask == True`) are needed. There is therefore about 2x more operations done for a square array.

On a 10K x 10K array, this catches up with us:

- `fast` takes 95ms, whereas
- `sum_antidiagonals` takes 208 ms.

**Comparison through range of sizes**

We'll use the lovely [`perfplot`](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/) package to compare speeds of a number of approaches through ranges of `n`:

```py
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.normal(size=(n, n)),
    kernels=[just_sum_0, fast, fast_g, nb_fast_i, nb_fast_ij, sum_antidiagonals],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(3, 16)],
    equality_check=None,  # because of just_sum_0
    xlabel='n',
    relative_to=1,
)
```

[image: speed of various approaches relative to fast()]

**Observations**

- As you can see, `sum_antidiagonals()` speed advantage over `fast()` is limited to a range of `n` roughly between 30 and 1000.
- It never beats the `numba` versions.
- `just_sum_0()`, which is simply the summation along `axis=0` (and thus a good bottom-line benchmark, almost impossible to beat), is only marginally faster for large arrays. That fact indicates that `fast()` is about as fast as it will get for large arrays.
- Surprisingly, `numba` detracts after a certain size (and that is after a first few runs to "burn in" the LLVM compilation). I am not sure why that is the case, but it seems to become significant for large arrays.

**Full code for the other functions**

(Including a simple generalization of `fast` to non-square arrays)

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def nb_fast_ij(a):
    # numba loves loops...
    r, c = a.shape
    z = np.zeros(c + r - 1, dtype=a.dtype)
    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            z[i+j] += a[i, j]
    return z

@njit
def nb_fast_i(a):
    r, c = a.shape
    z = np.zeros(c + r - 1, dtype=a.dtype)
    for i in range(r):
        z[i:i+c] += a[i, :]
    return z

def fast_g(a):
    # generalizes fast() to non-square arrays, also returns the same dtype
    r, c = a.shape
    z = np.zeros(c + r - 1, dtype=a.dtype)
    for i in range(r):
        z[i:i+c] += a[i]
    return z

def fast(A):
    # the OP's code
    n = A.shape[0]
    retval = np.zeros(2*n-1)
    for i in range(n):
        retval[i:(i+n)] += A[i, :]
    return retval

def just_sum_0(a):
    # for benchmarking comparison
    return a.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Your method of using ```as_strided``` is really nifty. Thanks for the extensive runtime analysis, it's interesting that the ```numba``` solutions are slower for large enough arrays. Credit for the ```fast``` solution goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088714/14923227

Comment: I noticed that the ```bincount``` method had the best runtime for small arrays (excluding any ```numba``` solution) and I made an edit to my post.

Comment: yes, I also looked at a `bincount` solution, but didn't include it because it gets quite a bit slower. Another one that I came up with last night is via `np.trace()`: a vectorized version, then `vtrace(np.fliplr(a), np.arange(n-1, -n, -1))`.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to speed-up (on my PC ~2/3 times) is use your `fast` method and `numba` package:

```
import numba
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def fastNumba(A):
    n = A.shape[0]
    retval = np.zeros(2*n-1)
    for i in range(n):
        retval[i:(i+n)] += A[i, :]
    return retval
```

But using `numba` makes sense only if this function is run multiple times. First evaluation of function takes more time (because of compilation).