# Average values over all offset diagonals

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to compute average values of shifted diagonals of a square array.

Given input matrix like (in reality much larger than 3x3):

```
[[a, b, c],
 [d, e, f],
 [g, h, i]]
```

correct answer would be

```
[g, (d+h)/2, (a+e+i)/3, (b+f)/2, c]
```

A code to compute such average could be:

```py
import numpy as np
def offset_diag_mean(mat):
    n = len(mat)
    return np.array([np.mean(np.diag(mat,k)) for k in range(-n+1,n)])
```

I assume one can do without a list comprehension (speed is quite important for me). Any clever solutions I'm missing?

Comment: How big are the array you want to compute in practice? Are the matrices always squared? What is the input type of the matrix (eg. `np.float64`)?

Comment: 1000 x 1000 at least, np.float, always square

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On efficient solution is to accumulate lines of the input 2D array directly in the output array at a specific position and then perform the division.

The idea is to zero-initialize an `output` array, then add `[a, b, c]` to `output[2:5]`, then add `[d, e, f]` to `output[1:4]` and then add `[g, h, i]` to `output[0:3]`. Finally, we can divide `result` by `[1, 2, 3, 2, 1]`.

Here is an implementation:

```py
# Use the decorator @nb.njit here to use Numba
def compute(mat):
    n = mat.shape[0]
    output = np.zeros(n*2-1, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        output[i:i+n] += mat[n-1-i]
    output[0:n] /= np.arange(1, n+1, 1, dtype=np.float64)
    output[n:]  /= np.arange(n-1, 0, -1, dtype=np.float64)
    return output
```

Here is the resulting performance on my machine on a 1000x1000 array:

```
Initial code:        15.31 ms
Kevin's code:         3.26 ms ( x4.7)
This code:            1.42 ms (x10.8)
This code + Numba:    0.66 ms (x23.2)
```

Thus, this implementation is **10.8 times faster** than the initial implementation and **2.3 times faster** than the fastest alternative version. Note that using Numba results in an even faster code with almost not change to the code: this Numba version is **23.2 times faster** than the initial implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The tricky part is summing the diagonals. I've [questioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336482/fastest-way-to-sum-columns-with-lag) multiple times in the past about the fastest approach to accomplish this.

One solution is to use `bincount`:

```
def offset_diag_mean(mat):
    n = len(mat)
    return np.array([np.mean(np.diag(mat,k)) for k in range(-n+1,n)])

def f(a):
    A = a[::-1]
    n = A.shape[0]
    indices = np.arange(2*n-1)
    indices = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(indices, A.shape, (8,8))
    triangle = np.r_[np.arange(1, n+1), np.arange(n-1, 0, -1)]
    return np.bincount(indices.ravel(), A.ravel()) / triangle

a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3) # 3x3 matrix example

assert (f(a) == offset_diag_mean(a)).all()
```

**Timings**

```
% timeit offset_diag_mean(a)
43.8 µs ± 962 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit f(a)
24.2 µs ± 362 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

For larger arrays:

```
a = np.arange(1024*1024).reshape(1024,1024)

%timeit offset_diag_mean(a)
21.5 ms ± 548 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit f(a)
8.71 ms ± 135 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This might give you an entry point to further optimize it. I would suggest [implementing it in c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67781178/14923227) or [use numba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67337060/14923227) for a considerable speedup.

Comment: I'm a bit confused but what's the difference between what you're doing and the offset parameter in diagonal function in let's say numpy? Is this faster?